# cannot find .sh script from the docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I have `Dockerfile` that looks like this

```
FROM alpine:3.7

WORKDIR /home/tmp

RUN apk add autoconf && apk add py-pip && apk add python3 &&\
    pip install --upgrade pip && pip install wheel
```

Originally I wanted to execute a `.sh` script on startup (via `ENTRYPOINT`) and immediately destroy the container. However as it failed to find the file I decided to do that manually.

I run container like this

```
docker run -it --rm -v c:/projects/mega-nz-sdk:/home/tmp mega_sdk_python
```

And it connects me to `bash` in the container.
In the list of files I can see the script I want to execute

```
/home/tmp # ls
Dockerfile   compile.sh   sdk-develop
/home/tmp #
```

However when I try to run it it cannot find the script

```
/home/tmp # ./compile.sh
/bin/sh: ./compile.sh: not found
/home/tmp #
```

What is the problem?

Script `compile.sh` looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

cd sdk-develop
sh autogen.sh
./configure --disable-silent-rules --enable-python --disable-examples &&\
make

cd /bindings/python

python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Ideally I would like to execute during instantiation of the container in order to have already configured container on startup (without need to run script each I run the container).

Comment: why do you say it does not find the entrypoint? Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @JoseAngelSanchez But there is a docker file on the top of the post. I just removed `Entrypoint` as it didn't work anyway as I attempted to run the script from inside the container. It was simple `ENTRYPOINT ./compile.sh`

Comment: that's the part I want to see, I think the problem is there, the best way to do this is with the ENTRYPOINT command, we should figure out why it is failing

Comment: It seems to be working when I execute script via `sh compile.sh`. I am using Alpine Linux, so maybe problem with that

Answer (score 3):

It seems in order to execute my `.sh` file I need to run it like this

```
sh compile.sh
```

So I added

```
CMD ["sh", "compile.sh"]
```

And I started to work (though failed with other errors like missing `make` etc. but that's due to missing packages in Alpine Linux itself so a separate matter).

Guess It is something to do with Alpine Linux itself. But I am not sure.

Comment: Its silly but this is exactly what I needed to see. I was doing an "sh" into the container using docker run -it <imagename> sh and then runserver.sh was working, but seeing this it now makes sense that I was essentially doing "sh runserver.sh".

Answer (score 1):

Alpine Linux is a very minimal distribution; it includes a minimal version of most Unix tools that conform to the POSIX specification, but no more.  In particular it does not include GNU Bash.

Your script doesn't actually use any special Bash features, so it would be enough to change the first line of the script to run the default system Bourne shell

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Using the Alpine `apk` package manager to install `bash` would work too, but it's not necessary for what you're showing here.

Usually you'd run the sorts of "compile" commands you show during the course of building an image, not when the image starts up.  I'd expect a much more typical Dockerfile to `COPY` the application source code and in then `RUN` the commands you show.  That would happen just once, when you `docker build` the image, and not every time you want to run the packaged application.

Comment: `Usually you'd run the sorts of "compile" commands you show during the course of building an image, not when the image starts up` That is exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you mounted the directory from your win host to the docker machine. I BELIEVE this is a permission problem - the file is not executable flagged.
Show detailed listing

```
# ls -lh
```

copy the folder to internal dir and add executable bit

```
cp /home/tmp /home/tmp2 -r
chmod +x /home/tmp2/*.sh
/home/tmp2/compile.sh
```

Comment: BTW docker for windows brings so many difficulties with mounting host folders ... this makes no fun

Comment: same issue `/bin/sh: /home/tmp2/compile.sh: not found` listing is `-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0              152 Dec 16 22:21 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0              316 Dec 16 21:44 compile.sh
drwxrwxrwx    2 0        0                0 Dec 16 21:12 sdk-develop`

Comment: the thing it in the past I did the same multiple times - I do it even now though I run `python` scripts from inside another docker project. however for some reason here it didn't work. If I create simply `python` file inside the folder and run inside the container via `python script.py` it works fine.